# Minikube exposed service url, get connection refused

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am experiencing issue with accessing the exposed service url from browser.
as shown in the image, all the pods are running and deployed successfully.

Help ?
[image]

here is the repo 
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bbachi/8233198cb5b49c919e54884eab227020/raw/3fff008f1f5cb7da4693a78ed299501fe18ce205/manifest.yml

Comment: I would suggest you enabling ingress using command `minikube addons enable ingress`
and then create an ingress to expose the service. Let me know if you need help with that. Loadbalancer type of service isnt going to work on minikube.

Comment: Can you post your yaml files in your question? It'll help us to understand/reproduce your scenario.

Comment: i have update the question with link to repo and yml file @mWatney

Comment: This seems LoadBalancer type service is not configured via a MiniKube. Please use the `ClusterIP` service type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because your nodejs application process is not listening on port 3000.Follow below to debug your service

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/

Comment: The only issue that i see from debugging is                                                         
 $ nslookup nodejs-api
Server:  84.208.20.110
Address: 84.208.20.110#53

** server can't find nodejs-api: NXDOMAIN

Comment: What is the content of /etc/resolv.conf inside the pod?